# How can I run my macro while looking at a different worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a database on a worksheet where data gets entered with the click of a button (I have a working macro for this).

I need to run the below macro sequentially but it gets an 'activate method of range class failed' error when I try run it without looking at the "Tool Database" worksheet.

How can I change my code to achieve the same autofill process without the need to have that worksheet open?

```
".Range("F" & lRow1).Activate"
```

> is where the runtime error '1004' occurs

```
Sub MacroB()
    
    Dim Output_Sh As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lRow1 As Long
    Dim lRow2 As Long
    Dim lRow3 As Long
    Dim lRow4 As Long
    Dim lRow5 As Long
    
    Set Output_Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool Database")
    
    With Output_Sh
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lRow1 = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        .Range("E" & lRow1).Activate
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Range(ActiveCell.Address), .Cells(lRow, ActiveCell.Column))
        
    End With
    
    With Output_Sh
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lRow2 = .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        .Range("F" & lRow1).Activate
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Range(ActiveCell.Address), .Cells(lRow, ActiveCell.Column))
        
    End With
    
    With Output_Sh
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lRow3 = .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        .Range("G" & lRow1).Activate
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Range(ActiveCell.Address), .Cells(lRow, ActiveCell.Column))
        
    End With
      
    With Output_Sh
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lRow3 = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        .Range("H" & lRow1).Activate
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Range(ActiveCell.Address), .Cells(lRow, ActiveCell.Column)), Type:=xlFillCopy
                
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to use `Select` and `Activate` in most cases.

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999)

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.AutoFill method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofill?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144083)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144187)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Sub MacroB()
    Dim Output_Sh As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lRow1 As Long, iCol As Long
    Set Output_Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool Database")
    With Output_Sh
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For iCol = 5 To 8  ' Col E to Col H
            lRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
            If lRow1 > lRow Then
                With .Cells(lRow, iCol)
                    .AutoFill Destination:=.Resize(lRow1 - lRow + 1), _
                        Type:=xlFillCopy
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```